# Mongomapper embedded document "Cannot serialize an object" error

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongomapper

I'm quite new to mongodb and I'm using sinatra and mongomapper to update the values of an embedded document with the following set up:

```
class TeamMember
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :name, String, :required => true

  many :team_member_projects
end

class TeamMemberProject
  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument

  key :date, Date, :required => true

  one :project 
end

class Project
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :name, String, :required => true
end
```

The modifier code is:

```
team_member = TeamMember.find(params[:team_member])
project = Project.find(params[:project])
date = Date.parse(params[:date])

tm_project = TeamMemberProject.new(:project => project, :date => date)
team_member.push(:team_member_projects => tm_project)
team_member.save
```

but I get the error for `.push` line:

```
BSON::InvalidDocument at /project/add
Cannot serialize an object of class TeamMemberProject into BSON.
```

Did I not declare my embedded document properly? Or is there another way to update embedded documents, I don't know about. I'm trying to use: http://mongomapper.com/documentation/plugins/modifiers.html#push

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work

```
team_member = TeamMember.find(params[:team_member])
project = Project.find(params[:project])
date = Date.parse(params[:date])

tm_project = TeamMemberProject.new(:project_id => project.id, :date => date)
team_member.team_member_projects << tm_project
team_member.save
```

It seems like I have to use `project.id`. Not sure why. Also not sure why my `.push` doesn't work, as I would have assumed it does the same thing as `<<`.

Comment: I've noticed the same thing... could be a bug. I would report one on github for that project and see what they say.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a bug.  The modifiers are just thin, convenient wrappers around MongoDB's modifiers.  Modifiers don't even update the relevant document in Ruby, they go straight to the database.  So, it makes sense that ".push" wouldn't be aware of MongoMapper associations.  `team_member.push(:team_member_projects => tm_project.to_mongo)` might work though.